# Three.js SpotLight class on an animating JSON mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to get a grasp on the three.js light classes. I've tinkered around with the three.js example in an attempt to get a 3D mesh model into the screen and add a basic rotate animation to it.

How do I achieve a static light source on the moving object? Currently the light reflected from the object seems to follow some path along the rotation.

Here's the code: http://codepen.io/jagomez8/pen/BzByEz

I've switched it out for various other light classes but I think the issue lies in the MeshPhongMaterial. When I apply flatShading to the material it renders the desired result except for the flat look it gets.The relevant code is on line 105.

```
if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );

        var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var egg;

        var matFloor = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
        var matBox = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x4080ff } );

        var geoFloor = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2000, 1, 2000 );
        var geoBox = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 3, 1, 2 );

        var mshFloor = new THREE.Mesh( geoFloor, matFloor );
        var mshBox = new THREE.Mesh( geoBox, matBox );

        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.1 );

        var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
        var lightHelper;

        var gui, guiElements, param = { color: '0xffffff' };

        function init() {

            renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
            renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

            renderer.gammaInput = true;
            renderer.gammaOutput = true;

            camera.position.set( 65, 8, - 10 );

            spotLight.position.set( 15, 40, 35 );
            spotLight.castShadow = true;
            spotLight.angle = Math.PI / 4;
            spotLight.penumbra = 0.05;
            spotLight.decay = 2;
            spotLight.distance = 200;
            spotLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
            spotLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
            spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
            spotLight.shadow.camera.far = 200;

            lightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper( spotLight );

            matFloor.color.set( 0x808080 );

            mshFloor.receiveShadow = true;
            mshFloor.position.set( 0, - 0.05, 0 );

            mshBox.castShadow = true;
            mshBox.position.set( 40, 1.8, 0 );

            scene.add( camera );
            scene.add( mshFloor );
            scene.add( mshBox );
            scene.add( ambient );
            scene.add( spotLight );
            scene.add( new THREE.AxisHelper( 10 ) );
            scene.add( lightHelper );

            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
            controls.minDistance = 20;
            controls.maxDistance = 500;
            controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
            controls.enablePan = false;
            controls.target.copy( mshBox.position );
            controls.update();

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onResize, false );


            var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
            manager.onProgress = function( item, loaded, total ) {

                console.log( item, loaded, total );

            };

            var onProgress = function( xhr ) {

                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {

                    var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                    console.log( Math.round( percentComplete, 2 ) + '% downloaded' );

                }

            };

            var onError = function( xhr ) {
            };

            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader( manager );
            loader.load( 'http://alexgdm.com/egg.json', function( geometry, material ) {
                ///****3D MESH***///
                egg = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0x050505, color: 0x0033ff, specular: 0x555555, shininess: 30/*, shading: THREE.FlatShading */}  )  );
                egg.position.set(0, 1, 1);


                scene.add( egg );
                animate();


            }, onProgress, onError );

        }

        function onResize() {

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            camera.aspect = ( window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight );
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        }

        function render() {

            lightHelper.update(); // required
            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            egg.rotation.y += 0.01;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }

        function clearGui() {

            if ( gui ) gui.destroy();

            gui = new dat.GUI();

            gui.open();

        }

        function buildGui() {

            clearGui();

            addGui( 'light color', spotLight.color.getHex(), function( val ) {

                spotLight.color.setHex( val );
                render();

            }, true );

            addGui( 'intensity', spotLight.intensity, function( val ) {

                spotLight.intensity = val;
                render();

            }, false, 0, 2 );

            addGui( 'distance', spotLight.distance, function( val ) {

                spotLight.distance = val;
                render();

            }, false, 0, 200 );

            addGui( 'angle', spotLight.angle, function( val ) {

                spotLight.angle = val;
                render();

            }, false, 0, Math.PI / 3 );

            addGui( 'penumbra', spotLight.penumbra, function( val ) {

                spotLight.penumbra = val;
                render();

            }, false, 0, 1 );

            addGui( 'decay', spotLight.decay, function( val ) {

                spotLight.decay = val;
                render();

            }, false, 1, 2 );

        }

        function addGui( name, value, callback, isColor, min, max ) {

            var node;
            param[ name ] = value;

            if ( isColor ) {

                node = gui.addColor( param, name ).onChange( function() {

                    callback( param[ name ] );

                } );

            } else if ( typeof value == 'object' ) {

                node = gui.add( param, name, value ).onChange( function() {

                    callback( param[ name ] );

                } );

            } else {

                node = gui.add( param, name, min, max ).onChange( function() {

                    callback( param[ name ] );

                } );

            }

            return node;

        }

        init();

        buildGui();

        render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your egg-shaped model is invalid. In particular, the vertex normals are not correct.

It appears that the vertex normals have the y-component and z-component switched. Try remapping them, and setting `.y = -.z`, and `.z = .y`.

Or, just call

```
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

That should result in reasonable vertex normals.

`THREE.VertexNormalsHelper` can be used to view the normals, if you want.

three.js r.77

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. How were you able to deduce that?